# Accepting a text style for a custom view

Tags: android

So I am writing my own custom view, that has both a TextView and an EditText within it. What I am trying to do is let the user set a text style for each one individually, like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="InputRow">
    <attr name="descriptionTextStyle" format="string" />
    <attr name="valueTextStyle" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I thought this would work, so that in XML I could say:

```
app:descriptionTextStyle="bold"
app:valueTextStyle="italic"
```

However, the problem comes when I am trying to read from the typed array. I can get the string:

```
if(typedArray.hasValue(R.styleable.InputRow_descriptionTextStyle)) {
   setDescriptionTextStyle(typedArray.getString(R.styleable.InputRow_descriptionTextStyle));
}
```

but when I want to call `descriptionTextView.setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style)` I need an integer value for the second parameter, which I don't have.

I can't change the style to be an int format, because then `="bold"` would be invalid, so I'm at a loss for how to get the text style.

Comment: see attrs file `<SDK>/platforms/android-XX/data/res/values/attrs.xml` and find `textStyle`

Comment: @pskink oooh okay I think I'm on to something here thanks

Comment: and however you could add `<attr name="android:textStyle" />` inside your `<declare-styleable>` there is no way to use two different `android:textStyle`s with a different name / alias

Comment: Yeah I knew the first one was an option, but again that means I can only use one text style, and only apply it to one of the two views (or both), but are you suggesting I can't give them different styles?

Comment: imho you have to repeat definitions of `android:textStyle`, like [this](http://pastebin.com/ZRQrHHAM)

Comment: i know its weird and redundant, since there should be a way of giving a name of custom attr and its format (data type): either basic type or user defined but afaik you cannot do that

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the suggestion from pskink, I took a look at how Android defines the style:

```
<!-- Default text typeface style. -->
<attr name="textStyle">
    <flag name="normal" value="0" />
    <flag name="bold" value="1" />
    <flag name="italic" value="2" />
</attr>
```

Given that, I was able to update my custom attribute accordingly:

```
<attr name="descriptionTextStyle">
    <flag name="normal" value="0" />
    <flag name="bold" value="1" />
    <flag name="italic" value="2" />
</attr>
```

Then I was able to setup my item by calling `app:descriptionTextStyle="bold"` and in the class I call `typedArray.getInt()` and call the `setTypeface()` method as I said. Thanks for the help!

Comment: and remember if you want only one such attr you can use existing `<attr name="android:textStyle" />`

Comment: Right, but I don't because I want to be able to apply different attrs to the TextView and the edittext @pskink

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

```
 public void setTypeface(Typeface tf);
```

method, it only requires a typeface parameter.

Also for converting string to typeface you can do something like this:

```
switch (typefaceString) {
case SANS:
tf = Typeface.SANS_SERIF;
break;

case SERIF:
tf = Typeface.SERIF;
break;

case MONOSPACE:
tf = Typeface.MONOSPACE;
break;
}
```